# Why php's session changes if I refresh a page?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

If I refresh a page, with a defaualt management PHP's session, the session is always the same; but if I use this class to save the session into DB, 
the session changes each time I refresh an page.

Why? Is it normal?

```
class SessionPDO implements SessionHandlerInterface
    {
       private $db;

       public function __construct($pdo)
       {
            $this->db = $pdo->getHandler();
            session_set_save_handler($this, true);
            $this->startSecureSession();
       }


       public function startSecureSession()
       {
            session_name("session_name");
            session_set_cookie_params(
                7200,          //expiration - 0 is when browser closes
                '/',           //path over which cookies will be sent
                null,          //domain for cookie to operate
                true,          //Secure cookie HTTPS only
                true           //HTTP Only/No Javascript access
            );

            $this->setSecureConfig();

            session_start();
       }


       public function setSecureConfig()
       {
            ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
            ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
            ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
            ini_set('session.hash_function', 'sha256');
            ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 6);
            ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom');
            ini_set('session.entropy_length', 1024);
            ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
       }

       public function open($path, $sessionName)
       {
           // open code
       }

       public function close()
       {
           // close code;
       }    

       public function read($sessionID)
       {
          // read code
       }    

       public function write($sessionID, $data)
       {
          // write code
       }    

       public function destroy($sessionID)
       {
           // destroy code
       }

       public function gc($max)
       {
           // gc code
       }
    }
```

Comment: Define "changes", what is different on each request?

Comment: @Oldskool the sessionID changes. With a default php's session, if I refresh 5 times a page, the sessionID is always the same; with my class no: I got 5 different sessionID, if I refresh 5 times a page.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I have to set session.cookie_secure on 0 because on localhost I'm not using a secure connection